# *.HTA with batch file user entered variables

Tags: batch-file, hta

I want to create a HTA that uses a batch file, when a user fills in the textboxes it will pass the data to the batch file.

My batch file is :

```
//batch
@ECHO OFF
CD "h:\tools\ffmpeg\bin"
set /p input="Enter input file: "
set /p output="Enter output file: "
ffmpeg.exe -i %input% %output%
```

I want to pass the input and output from the HTA to the batch file

```
set /p input="enter input"
set /p output="enter output"

%input% %output%
```

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you don't need to use a batch file at all for this.

Something like this should work:

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.run "h:\tools\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i " & Input & " " & Output
```

Note - I am just guessing at the variable names (Input and Output) you are using in the HTA, so you will have to rename those to whatever the variables are that contain the inputs you originally wanted to pass through to the batch file.  Also only guessing that it will be in VBScript...

EDIT:
To answer the comment more completely, something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="objTest" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTATest"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>
</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

    Sub TestSub
        Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Shell.run "h:\tools\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "& InputTextbox.Value & " " & OutputTextbox.Value
    End Sub

</SCRIPT>

<body>

    Input : <input type="text" name="InputTextbox" size="30"><P>
    Output: <input type="text" name="OutputTextbox" size="30"><P>
    <input id=runbutton  type="button" value="Run Script" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub">

</body>
```

**Note for people actually trying to pass arguments to a batch file from HTA:**
Assuming you've taken input from the user already you can pass it to the batch file (just like the parameters are passed to the EXE above), but you wouldn't need the `set /p` lines.  Instead you would reference input and output as `%1` and `%2` in the batch file.

Comment: How would I add this to the HTA and have a textbox for user input

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692603.aspx shows how to add a single textbox and retrieve its value.  You would just need to do two.

Comment: Updated the answer to show an example combining the original answer and the example from the link above.  It *should* work, assuming the path to that application exists.

Comment: No worries, if you could please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside it to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.